# How can one access Kotlin's `backtickedFunctions` from Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, syntax, idioms, language-interoperability

**TL;DR:**

Is there a simple syntax in java to access kotlins backticked functions such as `` fun `if`(){...} ``

**Long Version:**

In Kotlin, one may write the following class.

```kotlin
class ShapeShifter {
    fun speak() { println("Hello fellow hooman") }
    fun `speakLikeA`() { println("Meow") }
    fun `speakLikeA`() { println("Bwoof !") }
    fun `speakLikeA`() { println("NOOT NOOT ! (you would'nt have so much problems with linux ...)") }
}
```

And this would work just fine ... All your fellow kotlin-ers would be able to speak to you in all your forms like so :

```kotlin
ShapeShifter().`speakLikeA`() // would work like a charm
```

but when interracting with java-ist muggles your secret identity would be safe because I am pretty sure java-ists can only interract with you like so :

```java
new ShapeShifter().speak()
```

My question is :
Is there a way for java commoners to reach to your backticked kotlin functions *WITHOUT* resorting to using black magics such as introspection/reflection like so :

```java
var tomJedusor = new ShapeShifter();
ShapeShifter.class.getDeclaredMethod("speakLikeA").invoke(tomJedusor); //the forbidden arcane spell banned from Konoha ...
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can't: if the name of a class, method, or property in the bytecode isn't a valid Java identifier (if it's a language keyword, or has illegal characters), then any Java code trying to use it will fail to compile. Java provides no workarounds for that. — However, you can work around it from the Kotlin side, by changing the names in the bytecode; see ocos's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`@JvmName`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-level-functions) annotation lets you define jvm name for that method.

```kotlin
@JvmName("speakLikeACat")
fun `speakLikeA`() { println("Meow") }

@JvmName("speakLikeADog")
fun `speak like a `() { println("Bwoof") }
```

Now, you can access that method from java code.

```java
// .java 
shapeShifter.speakLikeACat();
shapeShifter.speakLikeADog();
```

Accesing *backticked* kotlin methods, fields from java is only possible with some `jvm annotations`. Kotlin compiler must obey `java` language specifications to generate the byte code. Actually java language specification does not allow this feature.

Comment: Nifty ! But let's assume that ```fun `speakLikeA`() { println("Meow") }``` is defined in a lib I have no control over ?
Is there a way to access it purely from Java while retaining compile-time verification ?

Comment: As gidds explained, it is not possible.
If a `pure kotlin library` is intended to be used also by java projects, the library design has to be `java` compatible.

Comment: Ok brilliant, this solves it for me then :)
I was just wondering if there was no new/obscure thingy in java that this would have been an occasion for me to discover ... I guess there is no groundbreaking discovery planned today but more knowledge is already real nice on it's own. thank you and @gidds :)

Comment: If you could just edit a bit your answer to specifically state said impossibility I'd accept it :)

Comment: Unicode characters are legal in java, as long as they are in UTF-16, so
`double π = Math.PI;` is valid. But  is outside of the Unicode baseplane, so that's why it's illegal.